# Cannot receive post parameter using forms created by PHP echo

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a webpage that allows you to add friends. For the confirm part I made a confirm button that made a post redirect to the confirm page:

```
while($rs=$friendsToConfirm->fetch_row()) {
    echo "Friends $count to confirm's ID: $rs[0]";
    echo "
    <form name=\"confirm\" method=\"post\" action=\"confirmfriend.php\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"userID\" value=\"$userID\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"friendID\" value=\"$rs[0]\">
    <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Confirm\">
    </form>
    ";
    echo "<br>";
    $count++;
}
```

The `$friendToConfirm` variable is all the friends needed to confirm and is retrieved from MySQL. When I hit the button, I was expected to receive the userID and friendID from confirmfriend.php, but I did not receive anything using `$_POST['userID'];`. Is there another way to do this or an I doing something wrong.

Comment: You have two hidden input fields with the same `name`, did you notice that?

Comment: @RajdeepPaul Sorry, that's a typo, updating. This typo is not on my PHP code.

Comment: @A-2-A It works for me

Comment: yeh now it will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because all of your forms have the same name [**confirm**]. You can try this:

```
$sl = 1;
while($rs=$friendsToConfirm->fetch_row()) {
    echo "Friends $count to confirm's ID: $rs[0]";
    echo "
    <form name=\"confirm{$sl}\" method=\"post\" action=\"confirmfriend.php\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"userID\" value=\"$userID\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"friendID\" value=\"$rs[0]\">
    <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Confirm\">
    </form>
    ";
    echo "<br>";
    $count++;
    $sl++;
}
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: please also address the problem of the `userdID` field

Comment: Oh yes. but ID is not important for server side, it's important for client side.

Comment: problem still exist, please chck

Answer (score 0):

Both of your hidden input fields are called "userId". I imagine the 2nd one needs to be renamed to "friendId".

All of the forms will also have the same name. It is usually preferred to ensure form names are unique.

If $_POST ['userId'] exists but is blank, check that $userId isn't blank.

To debug you can just var_dump the post array.

Comment: please also address the problem of the form name